# Can anybody suggest the best image resize script in php?

Tags: php, image, resize

HI

i need all types of images resize script in php

Comment: did you google for this?

Comment: You could try this script http://programanddesign.com/php/resize-images-using-this-php-script/

Answer (score 8):

> [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wiki/MainPage) is an object-oriented library for image manipulation, written in/for PHP 5. It's a pure-PHP library and doesn't require any external libraries apart from the GD2 extension.

i used it in a private project once, worked reasonably well for me.

#### Samples

```
// Chaining operations:
wiImage::load('image.png')->resize(50, 30)->saveToFile('new-image.jpg', 30);

// Load, crop, flip and output to browser in one line (no http headers included):
echo wiImage::load('image.png')->crop(30, 30, '50%', '50%')->flip()->asString('png');

// watermarking
$img = wiImage::load('pic.jpeg');
$watermark = wiImage::load('watermark.jpg');
$new_img = $img->merge($watermark, 40, 80);
```

Comment: FYI -- the WideImage library has a new location on sourforge: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a unix system, I highly recommend checking out [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and its various interfaces.  Fastest and most widely used image processing tools in the world.

Specifically, check out [MagickWand](http://www.magickwand.org/), one of the PHP interfaces.

Comment: +1 for ImageMagick, its dead simple fast and easy and can do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely use any wrapper for ImageMagick instead of the PHP GD lib, as the latter require you to set memory pretty darn high, and you're not always allowed to if you rent place  at webhotels. ImageMagick has many features as well besides just resizing.

Answer (score 1):

There a simple to use, open source library called [PHP Image Magician](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com/) that has some nice features and documentation.

Example of basis usage:

```
$magicianObj = new imageLib('racecar.jpg');
$magicianObj -> resizeImage(100, 200, 'crop');
$magicianObj -> saveImage('racecar_small.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious PHP-based solution would be reading the file with GD, getting the dimensions, calculating the new dimensions, scaling the image and outputting it.

Provided you have the GD extension, that is: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

There's also the Imagic extension which allows pretty straightforward resizing: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-scaleimage.php

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy: https://github.com/elboletaire/Watimage

```
$wm = new Watimage('test.png');
// Resize image to 400x400px
$wm->resize(array('type' => 'resizecrop', 'size' => 400));
// Flip it horitzontally
$wm->flip('horizontal');
// Rotate 90 degrees
$wm->rotate(90);
// Generate and save image
$wm->generate('test2.png');
```